# Pass a datetime from javascript to c# (Controller)

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

How do you pass a date time (i need it to the second) to c# using jquery and mvc3. This is what I have

```
var date = new Date();    
$.ajax(
   {
       type: "POST",
       url: "/Group/Refresh",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: "{ 'MyDate': " + date.toUTCString() + " }",
       success: function (result) {
           //do something
       },
       error: function (req, status, error) {
           //error                        
       }
   });
```

I can't figure out what format the date should be in, for C# to understand it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The following format should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("refresh", "group")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
        myDate: '2011-04-02 17:15:45'
    }),
    success: function (result) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        //error                        
    }
});
```

Comment: this would assume the browser/clients time and the server time are in sync, which wouldn't necessarily be the case.

Comment: @amonteiro, of course, you could always convert the data in universal time before sending so that on the server you could convert back to server local time.

Comment: This worked great.
How do I send a date that's NOT the second of April though, maybe a Date variable?

Comment: @sanepete I believe that you can provide any properly formatted date string or variable containing the date string and it will work.

Comment: @Owen, yes thanks, I ended up using something similar to:

data: JSON.stringify({ 
        myDate: myAwesomeDate
    }),

Answer (score 97):

Try to use toISOString(). It returns string in ISO8601 format.

GET method

javascript

```
$.get('/example/doGet?date=' + new Date().toISOString(), function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

c#

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult DoGet(DateTime date)
{
    return Json(date.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

POST method

javascript

```
$.post('/example/do', { date: date.toISOString() }, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

c#

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Do(DateTime date)
{
     return Json(date.ToString());
}
```

Comment: toISOString() is doing more not mentioned here. I converts the JS date to a utc date from 4th february 2018 it converts to 3th february 2018 2300Z and on server side I get then: 03/02/2018 23:00:00 so I have to do: myDate.ToLocalTime() (assumed current culture is DE) then I got 04.02.2018.

Comment: I correct: "...on server side I get then: 03/02/2018 22:00:00"

Answer (score 8):

There is a `toJSON()` method in javascript returns a string representation of the Date object. [toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/tojson#requirementsTitleToggle) is IE8+ and [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toisostring#requirementsTitleToggle) is IE9+. Both results in `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` format.

```
var date = new Date();    
    $.ajax(
       {
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Group/Refresh",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: "{ 'MyDate': " + date.toJSON() + " }",
           success: function (result) {
               //do something
           },
           error: function (req, status, error) {
               //error                        
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var date = new Date();    
$.ajax(
   {
       type: "POST",
       url: "/Group/Refresh",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: "{ 'MyDate': " + date.getTimezoneOffset() + " }",
       success: function (result) {
           //do something
       },
       error: function (req, status, error) {
           //error                        
       }
   });
```

In C#

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(double.Parse(MyDate)).ToString();
```

Comment: so DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(double.Parse(MyDate)).ToString(); would give me univeral time on the server right? If I do .ToLocalTime(), would it then convert that to server time?

Comment: actually now that I think of it, this would only give me the offset not the actual time being passed. so I would have to pass two variables - the offset like you posted, and the datetime like Darin posted

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Please see marked answer as a better solution to implement this. The following solution is no longer required.

Converting the json date to this format    "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss"
dateFormat is a jasondate format.js file found at [blog.stevenlevithan.com](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

```
var _meetStartTime = dateFormat(now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to wrap my datetime string like this:

```
"startdate": "\/Date(" + date() + ")\/"
```

Took me an hour to figure out how to enable the WCF service to give me back the error message which told me that XD

Answer (score -1):

```
var Ihours = Math.floor(TotMin / 60);
```

var Iminutes = TotMin  % 60;
var TotalTime =  Ihours+":"+Iminutes+':00';

```
   $.ajax({
            url: ../..,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",                
            data: JSON.stringify({objRoot: TotalTime}) ,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (er) {
                console.log(er);
            }
        });
```