# MVC Date Validation Attribute Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm wokring an a multi-culture site which needs to validate form input, specifically the date entered by a user on the front end.

The problem i'm having is that vallues for annotations need to be constants,. I currently have:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public string PreferredDate { get; set; }
```

However I would like the date format to be determined at runtime based on the culture, for example en-US would be MM/dd/yyyy whilst en-GB would be dd/MM/yyyy as above.

The problem as stated is that attribute arguments must be constants, so I can't do somethign like:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:" + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ToString() + "}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Well, is not a simple subject. When you have two culture to manage you need to localize your application. That will involve multiple layers of your application (from javascript to controllers/action and html/cshtml)

Comment: Since you can't have 2 `DisplayFormatAttribute` on a property and attribute arguments require constant values, you need to consider custom `IModelBinder` by changing default model binder depending on user's culture, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889038/asp-net-mvc-datetime-culture-issue-when-passing-value-back-to-controller for details.