# Nullable DateTimeOffset fromuri parameter in webapi 2 not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Given a action like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStatus(string dataflowId, [FromUri] DateTimeOffset? lastTime = null)
```

and client code with uri for accessing the Action:

```
DateTimeOffset? last = somedatetime;
/* DO REQUEST TO */ new Uri( flow.StatusUri + (last.HasValue? "?lastTime="+last.Value.ToString():""));
```

an exception is raized that it cant convert to Nullable'1 for the lastTIme.

What is needed instead of ToString() on client site for webapi 2 to be able to get the datetime from querystring

```
{"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"lastTime":["The value '1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM  00:00' is not valid for Nullable`1."]}}
```

Comment: Please post actual code and the actual exception

Comment: You'll need to UrlEncode that DateTime surely?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840762/how-do-you-urlencode-without-using-system-web  Can you post the actual URL this is hitting.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359566/webapi-utc-date-parameter

Comment: Updated the exception. and the code listed is the Actualy code. Using HttpClient to send a HttpRequestMessage.

Comment: System.Uri.EscapeDataString() was the solution

Answer (score 1):

Using Uri.EscapeDataString solved the issue.

```
new Uri(flow.StatusUri + (last.HasValue? "?lastTime="+Uri.EscapeDataString(last.Value.ToString()):""))
```