# Query string parameter with WebAPI routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

If I have an endpoint

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
    [HttpPatch]
    public IEnumerable<Order> UpdateOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
}
```

I can make the calls like this:

```
http://localhost/customers/1/orders
http://localhost/customers/bob/orders
http://localhost/customers/1234-5678/orders
```

But what if I want to send a date as part of the query string?

For example I want to send the following:
http://localhost/customers/1234-5678/orders?01-15-2019

How can I set my endpoint?

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
    [HttpPatch]
    public IEnumerable<Order> UpdateOrdersByCustomer(int customerId, DateTime? effectiveDate) { ... }
}
```

Comment: use this link I think it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359566/how-to-pass-a-datetime-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `[HttpPatch]` type of request, only [primitive types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx) are can be used as query strings. And `DateTime` is not a primitive type.

As your example suggests that you need to pass just the `date` part to the query string, therefore, you can use `string` datatype instead and convert it to date inside the action method. Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> UpdateOrdersByCustomer(int customerId, string effectiveDate)  //changed datatype of effectiveDate to string
{
    //converting string to DateTime? type
    DateTime? effDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(effectiveDate) ? default(DateTime?) : DateTime.Parse(str);

    // do some logic with date obtained above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your route attribute to the following:

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders/{effectiveDate?}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Order> UpdateOrdersByCustomer(int customerId, DateTime? effectiveDate) { ... }
}
```