# Passing and dealing with UK date formats from Jquery to C# Web API

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime, webapi, isodate

I've been developing an site and everything seemed to be going fine. I was sending my dates by converting them to ISO format as it's the only thing my C# WebAPI would accept (that I can work out). However I found that now we're in June and try for example to send 10/06/2021. The date sent would now have a day subtracted from them.

I've tried all sorts of different things. But they either turn out as invalid data or just in American format?

What I have tried:

```
var closeDate = convertDateTo($("#tbShiftDate").val());
```

which goes to:

```
function convertDateTo(dateStr) {
    var parts = dateStr.replace("/", "-").replace("/", "-");
    parts = parts.split("-")
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0])
}
```

Which returns **Fri Jun 11 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)**

But then

```
closeDate.toISOString()
```

Changes this to **2021-06-10T23:00:00.000Z**

I found this

```
closeDate = new Date($("#tbShiftDate").val()).toJSON();
```

But that ends up sending it in US format **2021-11-06T00:00:00.000Z**

Is there a way I can send the date like **2021-06-11T00:00:00.000Z**? Or do I have to send them to my controller as a string and then convert them into a DateTime there? Or is there another way I'm missing?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Send it to the controller as timestamp in the utc timezone.

Comment: see my updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string handling

```js
const convertDateToISO = dateStr => {
  const [dd, mm, yyyy] = dateStr.split("/")
  return `${yyyy}-${mm.padStart(2,"0")}-${dd.padStart(2,"0")}T00:00:00.000Z`;
}

console.log(convertDateToISO("13/6/2021"))
```

If you must use date, I normally normalise on 15:00 to not go over midnight and to not be bothered by winter/summertime

```js
const convertDateToISO = dateStr => {
  const [dd, mm, yyyy] = dateStr.split("/")
  return new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd, 15, 0, 0, 0) // normalise
    .toISOString()
    .split("T")[0]+"T00:00:00.000Z";
}

console.log(convertDateToISO("13/6/2021"))
```

However you might run into these issues:

[How to pass a datetime parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359566/how-to-pass-a-datetime-parameter)

Comment: Many thanks, this does the conversion through the JS fine, but returns 'invalid data' from the API.

Comment: Yes (thanks) however, this isn't accepted by my API as valid data which was also my issue mentioned. So I'm looking for a way that I can send and deal with at both ends that works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359566/how-to-pass-a-datetime-parameter

Comment: I'm not sure if you edited your original code? but I noticed it was "T00:00:000Z" rather than "T00:00:00.000Z". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I changed that hours ago