# sending a javascript date to .net object containing nullable System.DateTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to send a current datetime to a .net object, but no matter how I format the date, it exists just prior to the ajax call but the DateTime field in my object is null.

the ajax might look like this

```
l_endDate = new Date();
$.ajax({
        url: 'api/customer/' + l_id,
        type: 'Put',
        data:
        {
            id: l_id,
            endDate: l_endDate
        }
    });
```

and my c# might look like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, MyObject myObj)
```

MyObject has, among other attributes, an int id and a Nullable System.DateTime endDate. When I step through, I see the ID and other fields that I am populating in the ajax data contained within the object, but the endDate is null.

I see a lot of stack overflow references to converting .net DateTime to javascript, or casting the json date to a DateTime, but I have yet to find something that speaks to objects being sent via ajax.

any thoughts?

Comment: what version of asp.net mvc?  google for "post date to mvc" and you'll find all sorts of stuff

Comment: mvc5 - thanks i'll check that search

Comment: This was the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523870/pass-a-datetime-from-javascript-to-c-sharp-controller