# Comparing two datetime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I send a `datetime` using query `$post` to Mvc Controller;

1- On the server machine it doesn't bind well , some time in wrong format
I solved it by sending datetime as string then split the string to day, month , year.

2- Second problem; I parsed the `datetime` but when I compare it with another one it gives me wrong result.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28219557/1450855

Comment: Clear problem 

I post   "dd/MM/yyyy" 
but server reads null or "MM/dd/yyyy" =>x

when I compare x with Datetime .now => server give me that x is later than now 

but reality = > x is < Datetime.now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your date/time formatted in the ISO standard.

```
var myDate = new Date();
var dateString = myDate.toISOString();
```

Post dateString to your api.